# How to replace [cell] content from multi excel sheets with Python?

Tags: python, excel, vba, pandas

I have an Excel sheet，contains different units value ,like "hundred" and "thousand".

Now,I want change all "thousand" to "hundred",it means orginal cell value will [cell] times 10.

I use VBA solved this problem,I want to know how to use python to solve this problem?

> VBA like this :

```vb
Sub changecell()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i, t
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("b3:c5")
For Each i In rng
    t = t + 1
    If Not i Is Nothing Then
        If Right(i, 4) = "sand" Then
        rng(t) = Left(i, Len(i) - 8) * 10 & "hundred"
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

How to use python to replace these [cells] from multi excel sheets?
[image]

Comment: you cannot multiply strings. the way you have it written, you cannot do any math or analysis on your data without doing a lot of work of splitting strings and converting....  what were you thinking ??????

Comment: In excel, I can do this  without spliting strings and converting type.You can try it .

Comment: In fact,in my vba, I use Left(i, Len(i) - 8)  ,this pure nums, it can be multiply

Comment: stupid me ... i knew better, but i actually checked ... wasted my time  .... no you cannot do math directly on cell contents like what you have

Comment: again ... what were you thinking ???? you have to resort to extracting substrings. ..... why don't you insert a column between B and C and put the "hundred" into that column

Comment: I have thousand excel booksheets,  I really know insert other column,but It so boring.

Comment: too much work .... lol

Comment: In fact ,I have done all the jobs using EXCEL-VBA. When it runs,every excel opened,closed,opened ,closed......it wasted much time ,So ,I want to find the better ways,perhaps Pandas of Python?

Answer (score 2):

Save you excel sheet as csv file, then try this:

```
import csv 


with open('path_name_to_new_file', 'w', newline='') as newfile:
    with open('path_name_to_original_file', newline='') as original:
        writer = csv.writer(newfile, delimiter=',')
        reader = csv.reader(original, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader: 
            row[1] = row[1] * 10
            row[2] = row[2] * 10
            writer.writerow(row)
```

EDIT:

So, you have hundreds of excel files... and not all columns. Non tested code:

```
import pandas

 def test(cell):
    t = str(cell).split(' ')
    t = t[1] if len(t[1]) = 2 else None
    if t == 'thousand':
       return float(cell)*10
    else:
       return cell

excel_file_names = [##make a list of your file names##]
for file in excel_file_names:
    df = pandas.read_excel(file)
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        row['2016'] = test(row['2016'])
        row['2015'] = test(row['2015'])

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter()
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save(file + '_modified')
```

Comment: I only have xls type,converting thousand of excel sheet is hard.I consider use pandas.

Comment: Not every row ,every cloumn  has "thousand" in the sheet.Only some cell has 'thousand'

Comment: Use this method ,6 columns changes 60 columns

Comment: Thank for your help.This is the good melthod.But when I do this,I found the problem is harder than I think.First,the first row is blank;Second,the name of the column is nums.when I do this ,it appear:    df =pd.read_excel('00.xls')
_locate_stream(Workbook): seen

Comment: SO I upload the original file and the end file,the link is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0a6sHIFDtZeQnlMa0xnWk90cFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for your help.I upload the file,help me if you have time ,please give me a help,I will appreciate...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do it in Python use pandas

but this VBA will perform the replacements in all sheets of the current WorkBook:

---

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub GlobalReplaceThousandToHundred()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Variant, r As Long, c As Long, sz As Long

    Const STR1 = "thousand"
    Const STR2 = "hundred"

    sz = Len(STR1)

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ur = ws.UsedRange
        For r = LBound(ur) To UBound(ur)
            For c = LBound(ur, 2) To UBound(ur, 2)
                If Not IsError(ur(r, c)) Then
                    If LCase(Right(ur(r, c), sz)) = STR1 Then
                        ur(r, c) = Left(ur(r, c), Len(ur(r, c)) - sz) & STR2
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
        ws.UsedRange = ur
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Comment: If  cell endwith 'Thousand',[cell]*10;not replace 'hundred' with 'Thousand'

Comment: Thank you for your help,this is a good way,but here are thousand of files,When I do this ,The Excel,open,close,open,close,open,close.........I can't do other things at the time.And It will spends much more time.....

Comment: I upload the file ,the link is here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0a6sHIFDtZeQnlMa0xnWk90cFk/view?usp=sharing